# R data.table join, how to keep both columns that are joined on

Tags: r, data.table

```
A = data.table(idxA = rep(1:5, 2), valueA = runif(10))
B = data.table(idxB = rep(4:8, 2), valueB = runif(10))
C = A[B, on = .(idxA < idxB), allow.cartesian = TRUE]
```

How can I get the column `idxB` in the joined table `C`, ie for `C` to have both `idxA` and `idxB` columns?

Comment: Related: [Non-equi join using data.table: column missing from the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44282044/non-equi-join-using-data-table-column-missing-from-the-output). See the also last two sections on the `j` argument in `?data.table`.

Comment: Thanks, yes that's it. On the other hand, I do find R's way of documentation quite ineffective.