# Rename join-by variables when doing non-equi join with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to do a non-equi join between two `data.table`s (example to follow). Is there a way to rename the join-by variables in the `on` argument?

I tried the following but it does not produce the expected column names (`initial_date` and `final_date`). I know I can use `data.table::setnames()` to rename the variables.

```r
library(data.table)

dt1 <- data.table(id = c("a", "b"), 
                  initial_date = as.Date(c("2019-01-01", "2019-02-01")),
                  final_date = as.Date(c("2019-02-01", "2019-03-01")))
dt2 <- data.table(id = c("a", "a", "b", "b"), 
                  x = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                  date = as.Date(c("2019-01-01", "2019-01-04", "2019-02-03", "2019-02-19")))

dt2[dt1, 
    .(x = sum(x)),
    on = .(id, initial_date = date >= initial_date, final_date = date <= final_date), 
    by = .EACHI]
#>    id       date       date x
#> 1:  a 2019-01-01 2019-02-01 3
#> 2:  b 2019-02-01 2019-03-01 7
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: There are proposals for names to come from dt1 https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1700 but none to manually choose names with x = y >= z.

Comment: You could specify the columns you want and then remove the ones you don't after the join, not really ideal though. `dt2[dt1,
    on = .(id, initial_date = date >= initial_date, final_date = date <= final_date), by = .EACHI, .(x = sum(x), initial_date, final_date)][, c(names(dt1), "x"), with = FALSE]`

Comment: another option is to copy the columns before the join `dt2[, c("initial_date", "final_date") := .(date, date)][dt1, 
    .(x = sum(x)),
    on = .(id, initial_date >= initial_date, final_date <= final_date), 
    by = .EACHI]`