# Column name labelling in data.table joins

Tags: r, join, data.table, non-equi-join

I am trying to join data.table x to z using a non-equi join. Table x contains two columns X1 and X2 that are used as the range to use for joining with column Z1 in z. The current code successfully does the non-equi join however certain columns are removed or renamed. I would like to return the 'ideal' data.table supplied, instead of the one I currently have which I would have to rename columns or join data further to get the 'ideal' data supplied.

```
> library(data.table)
> 
> x <- data.table(Id  = c("A", "B", "C", "C"),
+                 X1  = c(1L, 3L, 5L, 7L),
+                 X2 = c(8L,12L,9L,18L),
+                 XY  = c("x2", "x4", "x6", "x8"))
> 
> z <- data.table(ID = "C", Z1 = 5:9, Z2 = paste0("z", 5:9))
> 
> x
   Id X1 X2 XY
1:  A  1  8 x2
2:  B  3 12 x4
3:  C  5  9 x6
4:  C  7 18 x8
> z
   ID Z1 Z2
1:  C  5 z5
2:  C  6 z6
3:  C  7 z7
4:  C  8 z8
5:  C  9 z9
> 
> # suboptimal data return data format
> x[z, on = .(Id == ID, X1 <= Z1, X2 >= Z1)]
   Id X1 X2 XY Z2
1:  C  5  5 x6 z5
2:  C  6  6 x6 z6
3:  C  7  7 x6 z7
4:  C  7  7 x8 z7
5:  C  8  8 x6 z8
6:  C  8  8 x8 z8
7:  C  9  9 x6 z9
8:  C  9  9 x8 z9
> 
> # column names are Id, X1 and X2 from x which replaces ID and Z1. The contents of X1 and X2 are also changed to the original values of Z1.
> # XY and Z2 remain unchanged.
> 
> # I want to create the following table where the original column names and values are retained, while still joining the table in a non-equi way.
> 
> ideal <- data.table(ID = c("C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
+                     Z1 = c(5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9),
+                     Z2 = c("Z5", "z6", "z7", "z7", "z8", "z8", "z9", "z9"),
+                     X1 = c(5, 5, 5, 7, 5, 7, 5, 7),
+                     X2 = c(9, 9, 9, 18, 9, 18, 9, 18),
+                     XY = c("x6", "x6", "x6", "x8", "x6", "x8", "x6", "x8"))
> 
> print(ideal)
   ID Z1 Z2 X1 X2 XY
1:  C  5 Z5  5  9 x6
2:  C  6 z6  5  9 x6
3:  C  7 z7  5  9 x6
4:  C  7 z7  7 18 x8
5:  C  8 z8  5  9 x6
6:  C  8 z8  7 18 x8
7:  C  9 z9  5  9 x6
8:  C  9 z9  7 18 x8
```

Comment: You can filter and sort columns in the j-expression: `x[z, on = .(Id == ID, X1 <= Z1, X2 >= Z1), .(ID, Z1, Z2, X1, X2, XY)]` Not very elegant, but works.

Comment: @Humpelstielzchen, some modifications should be made for this to work. see my answer :)

Comment: @mt1022 good job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up answering my own question.

```
data_table_tidy_join <- function(x,y, join_by){

    x <- data.table(x)
    y <- data.table(y)

    # Determine single join names
    single_join_names <- purrr::keep((stringr::str_split(join_by, "==|>=|<=")), ~length(.) == 1) %>% unlist()

    # cols from x that won't require as matching in i
    remove_from_x_names <- c(trimws(na.omit(stringr::str_extract(join_by, ".*(?=[=]{2})"))), single_join_names)

    # names need to keep
    x_names_keep_raw <- names(x)[!names(x) %in% remove_from_x_names]
    y_names_keep_raw <- names(y)

    # cols that exist in both x and y, but not being equi joined on
    cols_rename_index <- x_names_keep_raw[x_names_keep_raw %in% y_names_keep_raw]

    #rename so indexing works
    x_names_keep <- x_names_keep_raw
    y_names_keep <- y_names_keep_raw

    # give prefix to necessary vars
    x_names_keep[x_names_keep %in% cols_rename_index] <- paste("x.",cols_rename_index, sep ="")
    y_names_keep[y_names_keep %in% cols_rename_index] <- paste("i.",cols_rename_index, sep ="")

    # implement data.table call, keeping required cols
    joined_data <-
        x[y, on = join_by,
          mget(c(paste0("i.", y_names_keep_raw),paste0("x.", x_names_keep_raw))) %>% set_names(c(y_names_keep,x_names_keep)),
          mult = "all", allow.cartesian = TRUE, nomatch = NA] %>%
        as_tibble()

    return(joined_data)

}

> x <- data.table(Id  = c("A", "B", "C", "C"),
+                  X1  = c(1L, 3L, 5L, 7L),
+                  X2 = c(8L,12L,9L,18L),
+                  XY  = c("x2", "x4", "x6", "x8"))
>  
> z <- data.table(ID = "C", Z1 = 5:9, Z2 = paste0("z", 5:9))
>   
> data_table_tidy_join(x, z, join_by = c("Id == ID","X1 <= Z1", "X2 >= Z1"))
# A tibble: 8 x 6
  ID       Z1 Z2       X1    X2 XY   
  <chr> <int> <chr> <int> <int> <chr>
1 C         5 z5        5     9 x6   
2 C         6 z6        5     9 x6   
3 C         7 z7        5     9 x6   
4 C         7 z7        7    18 x8   
5 C         8 z8        5     9 x6   
6 C         8 z8        7    18 x8   
7 C         9 z9        5     9 x6   
8 C         9 z9        7    18 x8
```

Answer (score 2):

As commented by @Humpelstielzchen, it is possible to do by selecting the required columns manually. But one has to use the prefix `x.`(`x` in `x.` refers to the parameter `x` of `[.data.table` rather than the name of the data.table) to recover columns in the the original data.table `x`. Otherwise, incorrect output will be produced.

```
# desired
x[z, .(ID, Z1, Z2, X1 = x.X1, X2 = x.X2, XY), on = .(Id == ID, X1 <= Z1, X2 >= Z1)]
#    ID Z1 Z2 X1 X2 XY
# 1:  C  5 z5  5  9 x6
# 2:  C  6 z6  5  9 x6
# 3:  C  7 z7  5  9 x6
# 4:  C  7 z7  7 18 x8
# 5:  C  8 z8  5  9 x6
# 6:  C  8 z8  7 18 x8
# 7:  C  9 z9  5  9 x6
# 8:  C  9 z9  7 18 x8

# undesired
x[z, on = .(Id == ID, X1 <= Z1, X2 >= Z1), .(ID, Z1, Z2, X1, X2, XY)]
#    ID Z1 Z2 X1 X2 XY
# 1:  C  5 z5  5  5 x6
# 2:  C  6 z6  6  6 x6
# 3:  C  7 z7  7  7 x6
# 4:  C  7 z7  7  7 x8
# 5:  C  8 z8  8  8 x6
# 6:  C  8 z8  8  8 x8
# 7:  C  9 z9  9  9 x6
# 8:  C  9 z9  9  9 x8

packageVersion('data.table')
# '1.13.2'
```

---

In case that there are many other columns, which makes manual selection unfeasible, here is a workaround by repalcing the position of `x` and `z` during joining:

```
DT <- z[x, on = .(ID=Id, Z1 >= X1, Z1 <= X2), nomatch = NULL]
#' since for non-equi conditions, the values are from RHS while
#' the column names were from LHS, we known that `Z1` and `Z1.1`
#' correspond to `X1` and `X2`.
setnames(DT, c('Z1', 'Z1.1'), c('X1', 'X2'))
DT[z, Z1 := i.Z1, on = .(ID, Z2)]
# > DT
#    ID X1 Z2 X2 XY Z1
# 1:  C  5 z5  9 x6  5
# 2:  C  5 z6  9 x6  6
# 3:  C  5 z7  9 x6  7
# 4:  C  5 z8  9 x6  8
# 5:  C  5 z9  9 x6  9
# 6:  C  7 z7 18 x8  7
# 7:  C  7 z8 18 x8  8
# 8:  C  7 z9 18 x8  9
```

Comment: This seems like the best answer so far. Not quite sure how well it would generalise to much bigger data sets with many more columns. Having to manually add the columns is not a super efficient way of doing it. I wonder if this is just down to the data.table implementation? Or if there is different ways of doing the non-equi join.

Comment: More importantly, why does data.table relabel the columns used to join in the first place?

Comment: I don't known :(. However, by changing the order of the joins, it is possible to get the desired results without manually selecting columns, although the order of columns is diffferent from the `ideal` data.table.

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy?

```
copy_cols <- function(dt, nms) {
  dt[, paste0(".", nms) := lapply(.SD, copy), .SDcols = nms]
}

copy_cols(x, c("X1", "X2"))
copy_cols(z, "Z1")
x[z, on = .(Id == ID, .X1 <= .Z1, .X2 >= .Z1)][, c(".X1", ".X2") := NULL][]
```

Output

```
   Id X1 X2 XY Z1 Z2
1:  C  5  9 x6  5 z5
2:  C  5  9 x6  6 z6
3:  C  5  9 x6  7 z7
4:  C  7 18 x8  7 z7
5:  C  5  9 x6  8 z8
6:  C  7 18 x8  8 z8
7:  C  5  9 x6  9 z9
8:  C  7 18 x8  9 z9
```